# Using php i try to store urdu in mysql but it will stores question marks

Tags: php, mysql, store, urdu

i am getting data in Urdu language from feeds and when i store it in MySql it will store question marks in  the database. what should i do? I already set collation to utf8_general_ci .
here is the code below:
                $result = Domain::SpUrduNewsInsert($Url,$Title_utf8_string,
                    $summary_utf8_string, $DateObj,$content_hash , $news_image
                );

Comment: Why collation? What encoding (charset) did you set for the database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to deal with accents and strange characters in a database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33219970/how-to-deal-with-accents-and-strange-characters-in-a-database)

Comment: Set the connection charset to `utf8`. Have your tables use `utf8`. Collation is for **ordering** by alphabet characters, it has **nothing** to do with actual chars being saved.

Comment: Yep, I agree with Mjh. I would just suggest setting the encoding for the whole database rather than for each table (if you don't need to have different encoding for different tables). See my linked answer for details.

Comment: how i change mysql charset in phpmyadmin? can anyone help me ?

Comment: by default mysql database is in utf8 charset so why it stores question marks i tried every thing can anyone plz help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)