# json_encode sometime not working

Tags: php, mysql, json, unicode, encode

PHP version: **5.6.28**

---

I got strange issue, that `json_encode` working not everytime. What I mean:

I have simple connect.php file:

```
$questions = $con->prepare("
    SELECT Id, Question, Answer1, Answer2, Answer3
    FROM Questions AS q
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1
"); 
$questions->execute();

$questions->bind_result($id, $question, $answer1, $answer2, $answer3);
$questions->store_result();
$questions->fetch();

$qa = array('0' => $id, '1' => $question, '2' => $answer1, '3' => $answer2, '4' => $answer3);

echo json_encode($qa);
```

This PHP should select 1 random row with Id, question, answer1, answer2 & answer3 from database and later send It to Javascript.

When I refreshing page most of times I got blank page (1/10 it returns data). SQL query working correctly, when testing in phpMyAdmin It always selecting data.

If I'm using `var_dump` instead of `echo json_encode` It always selecting data, as expected. So seems that problem is with `json_encode`.

Data in database are in UTF-8 (included characters like `ąčęėįšųūž`) so I've also tried `echo json_encode($qa, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);` instead of `echo json_encode($qa);`, but the same problem, nothing changed.

I've also tried to use following function, but result the same:

```
function raw_json_encode($input, $flags = 0) {
    $fails = implode('|', array_filter(array(
        '\\\\',
        $flags & JSON_HEX_TAG ? 'u003[CE]' : '',
        $flags & JSON_HEX_AMP ? 'u0026' : '',
        $flags & JSON_HEX_APOS ? 'u0027' : '',
        $flags & JSON_HEX_QUOT ? 'u0022' : '',
    )));
    $pattern = "/\\\\(?:(?:$fails)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|u([0-9a-fA-F]{4}))/";
    $callback = function ($m) {
        return html_entity_decode("&#x$m[1];", ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    };
    return preg_replace_callback($pattern, $callback, json_encode($input, $flags));
}  
echo raw_json_encode($qa,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Also I've tried following function, but unsuccessfully too:

```
function jsonRemoveUnicodeSequences($struct) {
   return preg_replace("/\\\\u([a-f0-9]{4})/e", "iconv('UCS-4LE','UTF-8',pack('V', hexdec('U$1')))", json_encode($struct));
}

echo jsonRemoveUnicodeSequences($qa);
```

Have you any ideas how to solve It?

**UPDATE**

When I'm using `var_dump` It returns:

```
array(4) { ["question"]=> string(32) "Kiek kainuoja �is k?no losjonas?" ["a1"]=> string(10) " 9,99 " ["a2"]=> string(9) " 4,65 " ["a3"]=> string(6) " 15,29" }
```

`echo json_last_error();` returns: `5`

And `echo json_encode($qa);` do not return anything.

Also when I'm checking DEV tools via browser there I see message:

`HTML1300: Navigation occurred.`

I don't know If It have any relation with my problem.

And first time when I entering website I got following warning:

`DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337`

And after refresh page this warning disappear.

**UPDATE 2**

```
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx");


// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
```

Comment: Can you show us output of `var_dump` when `json_encode` returns nothing? And probably if `json_encode` return nothing - give us the output of `json_last_error()`

Comment: @vuryss thank you for attention, I've updated my question with info that you asked.

Comment: So you know what's the error - `5`. For others here, it would be good if you describe it as text (error message or constant name) instead of the number.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy when I',m using `echo json_last_error();` It returns me only number `5`.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy I fount at documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php that `5` = `JSON_ERROR_UTF8`

Comment: So you have malformed UTF-8 characters in the DB.

Comment: Yep, it's pretty clear, some characters in the DB are not valid UTF-8. You can try to plan with `iconv` before you feed the data in `json_encode` or just make sure that the data in the DB are valid.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy I've tried to use `$qa = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', utf8_encode($qa));
echo json_encode($qa);` but It now always returning `""`.

Comment: @vuryss In DB it contains characters like 'ąčęėįšųūž', It's lithuanian characters and I need to store them in database table.

Comment: Why `utf8_encode`? From the manual: *Encodes an ISO-8859-1 string to UTF-8*. I would use just `$qa` without that function there. Hopefully `iconv` will ignore (remove) broken UTF-8 characters. But it will break your texts anyway, it should just prevent your script from breaking. I would focus on fixing your encoding in the DB at first.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy Why `utf8_encode` I don't know, I found this sample at google. So what I need to do with my DB? Change collation or what? In DB those characters stored correctly (`ąčęėįšųūž`) and I can't remove those symbols, It will break words.

Comment: Can you check the character encoding that your DB Table has ?

Comment: @vuryss database collation: `utf8_general_ci`. Each varchar column on `Questions` table in that database have `utf8_general_ci` collation.

Comment: Ok then can you show us how you open the connection to the DB?

Comment: Did you set the charset to UTF8 when initializing the connection? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

Comment: Thank you for help, that solved me!

Comment: Don't do any replace() calls.  Don't use iconv().  Do use `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` -- but that only avoids `\u1234`.  Are there any remaining problems?

Comment: Collation has **nothing** to do with the encoding. Check what that word means. It's used only for sorting. Check [this my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33220497/971141) for details on the database encoding. There are many things which may cause the encoding to be broken.