Server Upgrade - Now my special characters are displaying incorrectly
Here is a link that explains the problem I'm now having
https://www.weblogism.com/item/270/why-does-e-become-a
On my old server the special characters were displaying fine. I started a new server with CentOS9 and installed all the latest versions of all software I'm using, mainly Apache, PHP (PHP-FPM) and MySQL.
All my code and databases are the same but now I'm having this special characters issue as shown above in the link.
I've changed all my charsets and encoding to UTF-8 (or utf8mb4_general_ci).
To simplify the issue, I'm directly outputting è from a php file to my website, the page has the UTF-8 charset encoding headers yet it still displays as Ã¨
Before I switched servers, this didn't happen - now at some point in reading the PHP file and outputting it to the website, there is some misinterpretation going on - What am I missing?

If everything in your stack is set to UTF-8 this problem does not happen, so the quest is finding out what isn't. When you say 'directly outputting' do you mean an echo statement without a database? Can you share this test script, the HTML output and the headers as seen by a browser?

Take a look at this answer, if it helps you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33219970/how-to-deal-with-accents-and-strange-characters-in-a-database

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

I approached it today with a fresh head. I just needed a bit of a nudge from you. I knew that phpmyadmin which is running on the same server was outputting the special chars correctly, so I worked through all the steps and eventually found a legacy piece of header code in PHP switching it to ISO-8859-1
